# Deletion CTE's in transaction is failing to remove duplicate records

Tags: database, postgresql, common-table-expression

Postgresql 10.1

*ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "doctorbilling_encounter_unique"
DETAIL:  Key (encounter_recid, uid)=(1, 39) already exists.*

I am attempting here to do the following:

-In the parent common_procedure table, I wish to change the description from "so is this" to "this is a test". This could easily cause a conflict in the common_procedure table if it results in two records having the same description, so the first CTE is intended to remove all conflicts in the common_procedure table.

-The first CTE is intended to remove any conflicts in the common_procedure table and return the UID from the record being removed as well as the record being kept.

-The second CTE is intended to move the reference from the (now deleted) common_procedure record to the kept common_procedure record (the good one).

-The last Delete is intended to clean up any resulting duplication in the doctor_billing table.

**THIS FAILS!** and every attempt I've made results in essentially the above error. It appears as though the delete aspects of the statement always occur before the insertions, so the tables are left in an error state.

**CAN THIS BE DONE?**

Thanks for any help or ideas.

```
BEGIN;

    SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;

    UPDATE common_procedures cp
    SET description = 'this is a test'          
    WHERE cp.description ='so is this';   


    WITH _t(bad_uid, good_uid) AS (
        DELETE FROM
            common_procedures a
                USING common_procedures b
        WHERE
            a.recid > b.recid             
            AND a.description = b.description
        RETURNING a.uid, b.uid
    ),
    _t1 AS (
        UPDATE doctor_billing
        SET uid = _t.good_uid
        FROM _t
        WHERE uid = _t.bad_uid          
    )
DELETE FROM
        doctor_billing a
            USING doctor_billing b, _t
    WHERE
        a.recid > b.recid             
        AND a.uid = b.uid AND a.encounter_recid = b.encounter_recid AND a.uid = _t.good_uid;

COMMIT;
```

Here are the table definitions (greatly simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE common_procedures
(
    uid integer NOT NULL,
    description text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT common_procedures_description_key UNIQUE (description)
        DEFERRABLE,
    CONSTRAINT common_procedures_uid UNIQUE (uid)
)

CREATE TABLE doctor_billing
(
    encounter_recid integer NOT NULL,
    uid integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT doctorbilling_encounter_unique UNIQUE (encounter_recid, uid)
        DEFERRABLE,
    CONSTRAINT doctor_billing_procedure_fk FOREIGN KEY (uid)
        REFERENCES nova.common_procedures (uid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        DEFERRABLE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. I believe the answer was posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13807067/1547335 Several years ago.

In short, two data modifying cte's using the same table should not be used together in the same statement. Here is a working version of the above (With PetaPoco @'s). Note that Data modification on different tables are being done at the same time, but the final Delete statements have been separated out.

```
BEGIN;
                                            SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;

                                            UPDATE common_procedures cp
                                            SET description =UPPER(TRIM( @0 ))                  
                                            WHERE UPPER(TRIM(cp.description)) = UPPER(TRIM(@1));    

                                            WITH _t(bad_uid, good_uid) AS (
                                                DELETE FROM
                                                    common_procedures a
                                                        USING common_procedures b
                                                WHERE
                                                    a.recid > b.recid            
                                                    AND a.description = b.description
                                                RETURNING a.uid, b.uid
                                            ),
                                             _t2 AS (
                                                UPDATE doctor_billing
                                                SET uid = _t.good_uid
                                                FROM _t
                                                WHERE uid = _t.bad_uid
                                            ),
                                            _t3 AS (
                                                UPDATE nurse_billing
                                                SET uid = _t.good_uid
                                                FROM _t
                                                WHERE uid = _t.bad_uid
                                            )
                                            UPDATE orders
                                            SET uid = _t.good_uid
                                            FROM _t
                                            WHERE uid = _t.bad_uid;

                                        DELETE FROM
                                                doctor_billing a
                                                    USING doctor_billing b
                                            WHERE
                                                a.recid > b.recid             
                                                AND a.uid = b.uid AND a.encounter_recid = b.encounter_recid;

                                        COMMIT;
```